# Docker runs only on Port 80

Tags: docker, nginx

I am unable to run my docker image on Port 4000, even though I can run it on Port 80. What am I doing wrong here?

```
FROM node:latest as build
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
FROM nginx:latest
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist/admin /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 4200
```

I'm creating the image using the following command:

> docker build --pull --rm -f "DockerFile" -t admin1:v1 "."

When I run it on port 80, I'm able to use it:

> docker run --rm -d  -p 4200:4200/tcp -p 80:80/tcp admin1:v1

However, when I run the following command, I'm unable to use it:

> docker run --rm -d  -p 4200:4200/tcp -p 4000:4000/tcp admin1:v1

I have researched similar questions online, but I haven't been able to fix the problem. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map the docker container port to the docker host port.

Try the following Command

```
docker run --rm -d -p 4200:4200/tcp -p 4000:80/tcp admin1:v1
```

The following is the extract from the Docker Documentation

```
-p 8080:80  Map TCP port 80 in the container to port 8080 on the Docker host.
```

You can refer the link for further information.
[Docker Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/)

Comment: Hello Jithendra, I am stuck in anothe problem. Can you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69579904/on-reload-angular-app-it-throws-404-error-in-docker